# make a python code that counts negative numbers in each list?

Tags: python, list

I am trying to make a `def count_neg()` function that counts negative numbers in each list? Like this:

```
>>> count_neg ([[0, -1], [-2,-4],[5,5],[4,-4]])
[1,2,0,1]
```

I tried making it and came up with this but the output did not count for each list?

```
def count_neg(*args):
    for i in args:
        counter = 0
        for j in i:
            if j < 0:
                counter += 1 
    print(counter)

count_neg([3,-2,0],[-1,-4,3])
```

Comment: Can you show us your output?

Comment: Just indent your print properly. Push it into the first loop by adding 4 spaces. It will print for each sublist that way.

Comment: Not really your question, but getting the result using a list comprehension is also fairly simple. `def count_neg(*args): return [sum(item<0 for item in lst) for lst in args]`. May be worth learning how they work.

Comment: Thank you! my output was just showing the total number of negative numbers. in this case, it just showed 3. However I wanted it in a list, for each given list. Thank you for your help everyone!! Have a blessed new year!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume from your question that you don't just want the total number of negative numbers in the 2D list but rather a list of the count of negative numbers in each inner list.

For that, you need to have a list of number of negative numbers that appear in the lists. The below solution would work fine -

```
def count_neg(*args):
    negative_counters = []
    for i in args:
        counter = 0
        for j in i:
            if j < 0:
                counter += 1 
        negative_counters.append(counter)
    print(negative_counters)
```

Comment: Happy to help :) If you liked my answer and it solved your issue, please upvote my answer and select it as the correct answer

Answer (score 2):

It's because of printing the counter at the wrong place. It should be inside of outer loop rather than at the end of function.

```py
def count_neg(*args):
    for i in args:
        counter = 0
        for j in i:
            if j < 0:
                counter += 1 
        print(counter)

count_neg([0, -1], [-2,-4], [5,5], [4,-4])
```

Output

```
1
2
0
1
```

Answer (score 0):

This works properly:

```
>>> def count_neg(*args):
...     result = []
...     for i in args:
...         counter = 0
...         for j in i:
...             if j < 0:
...                 counter += 1
...         result.append(counter)
...     return result
... 
>>> count_neg([3,-2,0],[-1,-4,3])
[1, 2]
>>> count_neg ([0, -1], [-2,-4],[5,5],[4,-4])
[1, 2, 0, 1]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

hi please use this code

```
def count_neg(*args):
    counter=[]
    for i in args:
        count=0
        for j in i:
            if j<0:
                count+=1
        if count>0:
            counter.append(count)     
    print(counter)

count_neg([3,-2,0],[-1,-4,3])
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I did not make the empty list that is why it did not work. Have a blessed day